# CRM 2011 Xrm . audit records return system user instead of logged one

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I created application using CRM 2011 SDK.

While retrieving audit record i use recommended code.
My code looks like this:

```
using (_serviceProxy = ServerConnection.GetOrganizationProxy(serverConfig))
{
    _service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;
    RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest changeRequest = new RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest();
    changeRequest.Target = new EntityReference(Static.IncidnentsEntityName, new Guid(id));

    RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse changeResponse =
                        (RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse)_service.Execute(changeRequest);

    return changeResponse.AuditDetailCollection.AuditDetails.SelectMany(s => createAuditRecord(s)).ToList();
}
```

where `createAuditRecord` function just unpacks attributes. There is an attribute called `userid`, but it always returns system user, under which my app is calling CRM, but not the logged user.

While directly querying SQL ,I've found that there is an information about logged user.

[image]

Is there some way to extract this information without directly extracting data from DB?

Comment: Please include the code you are using for `createAuditRecord`.

Comment: var inrecord = detail.AuditRecord;
                var res = new List<AuditRecord>();
                var date = inrecord.Attributes.SafeToDateTime("createdon");
                var action = inrecord.Attributes.getOption(Static.AuditName, "action").Text;
                var user = inrecord.Attributes.toEntity<BaseEntity>(Static.AuditName, "userid").Name;

Comment: @alekoo73 Add that code to your initial post, ideally with the full definition of the function

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to extract information directly from database if it's for external use or reports. It's much faster, you can do complexier queries and you will save a lot of time. There no plus value of using the SDK to read data other than being sure it gonna be supported in the next version and supported online.